# IE+jQuery+Ajax+XHTML: HTML getting clipped after .html() or .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, xhtml, innerhtml

This is a really hard problem to put into a brief sentence, so I apologize if I kill it.

I launched a site recently which had been extensively tested on my local web server on all my desired browser platforms, including IE8 (IE8 standards mode, XHTML Strict).  I encountered no problems at all until the site went live on a dedicated web server.

The site uses `jQuery.get()` on the `change` event for the `input` elements of a form, where the response is grafted into a common `<div id="results"></div>`.

Despite the caching woes I've read about with IE and XMLHTTPRequest, my problem seems to take place AFTER my ajax callback begins execution.  My callback (supplied via `.get()` / `.load()`-- I've tried both) receives an HTML fragment returned by my server.  Testing the returned content in any browser reveals exactly what I expect the content to be.

However, as soon as I put the HTML fragment into the DOM tree in the `#results`, IE actually clips the first 7 or 8 opening tags off of my markup (along with the children of most of those tags).  It's wickedly bizarre.  I fixed it in another area of the site by setting the HTML content via `jQuery('#results')[0].innerHTML = content`, but no dice this time.

Example response:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">some link</a>
    <span>stuff, blah blah</span>
    <a href="#">another link</a>

    <ul>
        <li id="item-2342">
            <img src="#" />
            <div class="info">
                <h6> ..title.. </h6>
                <a href="#">View</a>
                <span rel="stats"> ..statistics.. </span>
            </div>
        </li>

        <!-- ... and so on in a loop over items to create more <li> items ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Literally EVERYTHING up through the opening tag of that `<span rel="stats">` is truncated.  The effect is that IE displays my returned AJAX content as if it were to begin with the text node: `..statistics.. </span>`.  (I tried removing the `rel="stats"` at the suggestion of a comment below, changing it to a CSS class instead, but the same result occurs.)

If I request my AJAX url directly via the browser's URL field, the returned content is perfect.

If I use `alert()` to display the AJAX content returned, it is perfect.

If I assign my AJAX content via `.html()` or `.innerHTML`, it is immediately truncated.

Sooo.... WTF?  IE's (crappy) debugger displays no script errors or anything of that nature.  Has anybody ever dealt with this kind of issue before?  Again, I add emphasis to the fact that on my development server (127.0.0.1), IE has no problems, and it seems to use the same "mode" (IE8 Standards) and everything.

EDIT: Here is the Javascript powering the AJAX lookup:

```
jQuery('.ajax-panel').live('load', function(event, request_string){
    var panel = jQuery(this).stop(true).fadeTo(100, 0.2).addClass('loading');
    var form = jQuery(panel.attr('rel'));
    jQuery.get(form.attr('action'), request_string ? request_string : form.serialize(), function(response){

        // WTF?
        // panel[0].innerHTML = response;
        panel.empty().append(response);

        // Carry on.
        panel.removeClass('loading').stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have an example page, so we can try this?

Comment: Just curious, have you tried to assign some different content to .innerHTML in response handler?  That could give an idea what causes error (text length, specific tags, etc...).

Comment: And are you trying this in IE8 in IE8 mode or in IE7 compatibility mode?

Comment: IE8 standards mode.  I declare the doctype to be XHTML strict.

Example page (shortened, lots of GET params): http://bit.ly/9EULaH

The page loads, it assesses the `<form>` I mentioned, and then triggers the ajax and places the result in `<div id="ajax-panel">`.  That JS work takes place in `/media/js/base.js` in the function on lines 32-44.

Here's where I cross my fingers and hope that you see the same ghosts that I see :) 

@NikitaRybak
It doesn't appear to matter what the length of the ajax response-- whether there's one `<li>` or ten.  I'll have to test some more with different content.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue happen where part of the html code appended was clipped, but if I created an alert of the inner html, or forced a scroll, it appeared.

I then came across an article that seemed to indicate that IE8 was not redrawing the pane correctly.
http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript

The only way I managed to get it to work was to add a class to it, wait, then remove the class. If I did not wait, it seems to skip execution.

```
function Redraw(element)
{
 if ($.browser.msie)
 {
  element.addClass("invisible");
  setTimeout(function(){
    element.removeClass("invisible");
   },1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove `rel="stats"`?

The `rel` attribute is not allowed to have `stats` in it, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534366%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Same results.  Oddly, I use a few non-standard `rel` values without any other side effects, including several other instances in the same chunk of HTML, none of which suffer this problem.  Note that all of the following `<li>` entries in my AJAX HTML remain unharmed.  Only the first one goes down in flames (with the HTML leading up to it)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the problem.  I have generated a similar AJAX response to the original submitter.  Some initial info, then a loop through the data to create 8 different div's worth of content.  When running the page, it would do the load, but IE would only show some of the data.  One small change fixed this.

I had a span on the page (for a set of video tags) within each div, so that I could truncate text if it was too long, and use the span with the title attribute as a hovertip.  If the tag span was formatted this way:

```
<div>Tags: <span title="Miller, Jackson, Brown">Miller, Jackson...</div>
```

it wouldn't work, whereas:

```
<div>Tags: Miller, Jackson, Brown</div>
```

worked fine.  Of course, I noticed my error in that there is no span closing tag.  Fixing this also worked, but the important thing that I noticed is that IE seems to be very intolerant of formatting errors on AJAX, or, more correctly, AHAH.

I would, after having seen this, guarantee that there is some slightly malformed HTML in the return string.  I had the exact same error, a fragment of information returned by javascript, that you did, and correcting the error fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess, but it helped me once with an IE problem:

Instead of `$('your_container').html( your_content )`, try to empty the container object entirely, then use `append()`. So:

```
$('your_container').empty().append( your_content );
```

It's IE. You never know.

Comment: Everybody loves a never-know on top of a never-know.

Comment: Be it jQuery or IE, this doesn't work either.  I'm pretty sure I'm not being deceived by cached ajax responses-- it appears to behave exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your METHODS to POST. The default is GET.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'), 
    success: function(){
        panel.empty().append(response);

        // Carry on.
        panel.removeClass('loading').stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
    }
});
```

That should do it... I know I'm missing some stuff from your functions, but this is the jist of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I was using jQuery's .html() to insert response from the server.
The beginning of the response text began with some php followed by a line break and then some HTML. Just removing the line break caused the truncation to stop.

From:

```
<?php 
$this->load->helper('stdclass_helper');
?>

<div id="expense_entry" class="element_record" style="padding:20px;"
```

To:

```
<?php 
$this->load->helper('stdclass_helper');
?>
<div id="expense_entry" class="element_record" style="padding:20px;"
```

After a few experiments, I was able to isolate the cause of *my* problem to line breaks at the beginning of the file.

For example, truncation occurs beginning file (quotes added to show line breaks):

```
"



<div id="expense_entry" class="element_record" style="padding:20px;" saveHandler="Accounting.Expenses.saveExpense">
<!-- BEGIN EXPENSE ENTRY FORM -->
<?php 
$this->load->helper('stdclass_helper');
?>
"
```

Truncation goes away by removing those first line breaks.

This was using jquery-1.6.4.min.js and IE 9 (in IE 8 emulation mode) on Windows 7 (using VMWare virtual windows machine)

Update:
Being a thorough guy, since I am already using a wrapper around the jquery .html() function to find and register custom elements, I went ahead and took care of the IE problem by trimming any data that was a string. This works well:

```
// Override jQuery's html() method, so that we can register any special elements in new html.
(function( $, oldHtmlMethod ){

    // Override the core html method in the jQuery object.
    $.fn.html = function(data){
        // Execute the original HTML method using the
        // augmented arguments collection.
        //trim whitespace that could cause IE to truncate returned content
        **if(typeof data == 'string'){
            data = data.trim();
        }**
        var results = oldHtmlMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        return results;

    };

})( jQuery, jQuery.fn.html );
```

This works well for me.